# Why do I need a type annotation here?

Tags: f#

In the following code:

```
type ParseResult<'a> =
    {
        Result : Option<'a>;
        Rest : string
    }

type Parser<'a> = string -> ParseResult<'a>

let ThenBind p (f : Option<'a> -> Parser<'b>) : Parser<'b> =
    fun input ->
        let r = p input
        match r.Result with
        | None -> { Result = None; Rest = input }
        | _ -> (f r.Result) r.Rest
```

With the type annotation for f, the type for ThenBind is:

```
p:(string -> ParseResult<'a>) ->
f:(Option<'a> -> Parser<'b>) ->
input:string -> ParseResult<'b>
```

But without the annotation, it's:

```
p:(string -> ParseResult<'a>) ->
f:(Option<'a> -> string -> ParseResult<'b>) ->
input:string -> ParseResult<'b>
```

Why?

Comment: An OT tip. Creating a new Rest string for each parser result is rather ineffficient. A more efficient approach is to add a string position.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You don't need a type annotation. The two types are identical.

`Parser<'a>` is just an alias `string -> ParseResult<'a>`, so it makes no difference whether the result type of `f` is declared as `Parser<'b>` or `string -> ParseResult<'b>`. They're the exact same type.